# Awarding a manual bounty for helpful answer

Tags: discussion, bounties

I made a very silly mistake in iOS and it was delaying my app release indefinitely. I asked the question without getting a single response until a user finally suggested what I was doing wrong.

In my eyes I see this answer as being very helpful but I also see bounty type answers as very detailed, specific and taking a lot of effort and thought to answer.

I always want to use Stack Overflow in the most appropriate way. Is it appropriate to award a bounty manually to a person because of how helpful it was to me in my situation or is it really meant for exceptional answers?

I want to give the answerer an extra 50 points of reputation for being able to pinpoint exactly what I did wrong. Is that an acceptable use of bounties?

Comment: There is an explicit *Award an existing answer* option in the bounty wizard for that.

Comment: @juergend, I know and I saw that. What I was trying to ask really is if "helpful to me" is a valid reason to award a bounty or does it really have to be an involved exceptionally answered question.

Comment: It's your rep. You can award it like you want to. I guess most people award bouties because they were helpful to themselfs.

Comment: @juergend well then I guess that answered my question :). Feel free to put an answer in and I will accept it. I have great respect for Stack Overflow and I dont want to do anything that is outside of the standard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bounty wizard has an explicit option for that:

[image: bounty wizard]

And since it is your reputation points you spent, it is your choice on what.